# A guitar riff playing in episode 80 and 85 of My Hero Academia season 4

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

In *My Hero Academia* season 4 episode 80 at around 3:05, there's a guitar riff playing. The same riff is also playing in episode 85.

What is this OST?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is *Sorezore no Mokuhyou* ([Spotify link](https://open.spotify.com/track/0tgvLHWXtux0AIyBLTciJk?si=nPsjUSlDRveLjSMTSBFi4Q))  by Yuki Hayashi, the 5th track in *Boku no Hero Academia Season 2 OST* album.